# window.trustedtypes in undefined in Firefox

Tags: angular, security, firefox, xss, trusted-types

I have implemented trusted types in my application.which is working fine in Chrome.but in firefox i'm getting window.trustedtypes is undefined in Firefox error.please suggest how to solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is old, but some explanation for someone who comes across this question:

Check the following link for supported browsers:
https://caniuse.com/trusted-types

Firefox currently does not support trusted types. It is possible to use them with the polyfill from w3c: https://github.com/w3c/trusted-types